# Which Boolean type should I use in iOS/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, types

It looks like there are four alternatives.

1. BOOL
2. bool
3. Boolean
4. boolean_t

Which one should I use?

There seems to be two definitions of false too.

1. false
2. FALSE

Which one should I use?

Comment: better use BOOL and FALSE

Comment: It's framework bloat like this that is a pain for devs. Anyone reminded of the tax system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common is `BOOL` with `YES`, `NO` defs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BOOL` type for boolean.

And use `NO` to set false.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` is the one offered by objective-C, so stick with it unless it becomes a problem (this is a very rare case, but it happened to me once).  Also, there are more definitions for true and false:  `YES` and `NO` are the most objective-C like.  They are defined as the clang literals, so it is best to use them.

Answer (score 1):

It will vary on the API you are calling.  Each API will have its own convention.   For most of the Apple Obj-C stuff, it is BOOL with YES/NO defined.   However, you may end up working with another library that has its own convention (e.g. boolean_t) - in calls to that library match the convention.  For your own stuff, I'd stick to the Obj-C method.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `BOOL` and `FALSE` OR `NO`

Hope it helps you